# changing textinput text when clicked in a kv file

Tags: python, kivy

Im trying to change the text of the textinput when the user clicks into it. ive tried the def on_enter, but in the whole file im using a screen, so thats out the window.

```
def test(self, *args):
    self.ids.text_input.text = "test"
    #self.ids.text_input.bind(on_text_validate = self.test)?


TextInput:
    multiline: False
    id: text_input
    text:'00:00'
    on_enter: app.test() #? problem area
    on_press: app.test() #? problem area
```

Comment: maybe better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run - to test problem and create solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on_focus` instead of `on_enter` or `on_press`:

```
TextInput:
    multiline: False
    id: text_input
    text:'00:00'
    on_focus: app.test(self)  # call app.test() and pass reference to the TextInput
```

Then the method in the `App` can be:

```
def test(self, ti):
    ti.text = "test"
```